Java Spring customer Validators not working
I am attempting to create a custom validation rule for my Java Spring API. I have CredentialCreateDTO which has an array of strings called validRedirectUris. I am trying to check that each string in validRedirectUris is a valid URL.
Here is my code:
package main.controller;

import main.dto.credentials.CredentialCreateDTO;
import main.model.Credential;
import main.response.BaseResponse;
import main.service.CredentialsService;

import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/oauth/credentials")
public class CredentialsController {

    private final CredentialsService credentialsService;

    @Autowired
    public CredentialsController(CredentialsService credentialsService) {
        this.credentialsService = credentialsService;
    }

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<Credential>> createCredentials(@Valid @RequestBody CredentialCreateDTO credentialCreateDto) {
        Credential credential = credentialsService.createCredentials(credentialCreateDto);
        BaseResponse<Credential> response = new BaseResponse<Credential>(credential, "credential", "/oauth/credentials");
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
}


package main.dto.credentials;

import main.util.ValidUrl;

import java.util.List;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Getter
@Setter
public class CredentialCreateDTO {
    @NotNull(message = "validRedirectUris cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "validRedirectUris must have at least one element")
    @ValidUrl(message = "Invalid URL")
    private List<String> validRedirectUris;

    @NotNull(message = "scopes cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 1, message = "validRedirectUris must have at least one element")
    private List<String> scopes;

    // Constructor
    public CredentialCreateDTO(List<String> validRedirectUris, List<String> scopes) {
        this.validRedirectUris = validRedirectUris;
        this.scopes = scopes;
    }

    // Default constructor for deserialization
    public CredentialCreateDTO() {
    }
}


package main.util;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UrlValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidUrl {
    String message() default "Invalid URL";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}


package main.util;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

public class UrlValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidUrl, List<String>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidUrl constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<String> urls, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (urls == null) {
            return true; // Use @NotNull if null is not allowed
        }

        for (String url : urls) {
            try {
                URI uri = new URI(url);
                uri.toURL();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}


I have tried debugging by adding System.outs, breakpoints etc.
It doesn't seem to be running the .isValid function, despite compiling and running correctly.

You are missing the @Validated annotation on your @RestController. Without it SpringMVC doesn't validate parameters of your methods.
And as @Mar-Z pointed out your ConstraintValidator does not use the correct imports, still pointing to javax.validation instead of jakarta.validation

AFAIK this is not necessary in the current Spring Boot 3.

It is necessary. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-valid-vs-validated

Well. The above tutorial confirms that Validated annotation on class level is not needed if only Valid annotation on objects is in use. This is the case in the code posted in the question.

Ok you seem to be right, I'll re-check that later

The problem here is that your project is mixing old, Spring Boot 2, javax.validation and new, Spring Boot 3, jakarta.validation libraries. This can be seen in the imports.
Solution
Either remove the old dependencies or edit your import statements manually.
